# Shift + wheel and Ctrl + wheel doesn't work anymore in Blender 2.8?

Tags: shortcut

In 2.7.x it's usefull to pan only in horizontal or vertical, which I use a lot. I searched everywhere and didn't figure out, it doesn't work anymore? This page here https://developer.blender.org/T55194 says just "NO REPLACEMENT".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about unfinished features in experimental versions of Blender

Comment: So, it doesn't exist in the beta? Don't know how could it be off topic, it still Blender and the Beta version, it's almost finished, maybe the shortcut change. Your comment is useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem manually add key map item in the preferences.

User preferences - Input - 3D View - 3D View Global - Add new - in field "Identifier operator to call on input event" type **view3d.view_pan** - then choose your key and action Pan left or right \ up or down.

This is not solved by Import key configuration from blender 2.79.

---

On Blender 2.83.4:

1. Click **Edit > Preferences**.
2. Click the **Keymap** tab.
3. Expand **3D View**.
4. Expand **3D View (Global)**.
5. Scroll to **Pan View Direction**.

At this point, you can change the options to suit your preferences.

[image: Pan View Direction]

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so here is an answer:

Fairly sure this is not possible in 2.8 for the moment. This requires specific RNA (?) in the hotkey bind (you can see this in 2.79 when you search using hotkey and for "shift scrollwheel" where there is this unique RNA and "panning" tab on the hotkey you can't get by creating new hotkey) 
Since there is no default hotkey entry for this in 2.8 I don't think you can make this without coding. (I tweeted at Pablo, though, so if he happens to reply with solution I'll update here)

Comment: I hope it is not removed, I use this shortcut quite a bit.

Comment: It would be rather big loss :/ but I'm sure it will make eventual return.

Answer (score 0):

It is *User Preferences - Keymap*, not *Input*.

A viable alternative is to activate *Zoom to Mouse Position*:

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please upload images using the built-in uploader: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post Thanks.